# Referencing with optidef doesn't work

Tags: hyperref, optidef

I have an optimization problem with my own label (P). However, `\ref{e}` refers to the optimization problem and not to the equation. Without \tag(P) everything works. Any way how to tackle this?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{optidef}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{mini}|s|
    {}{c^\top x}
    {\tag{P}\label{P}}
    {}
    \addConstraint{Ax}{=b}
    \addConstraint{x}{\geq 0}.
\end{mini}

\begin{align}
    1+e^{i \pi} = 0 \label{e}
\end{align} 

Reference to \ref{P}

Reference to \ref{e}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: unrelated but `LaTeX Warning: Command \i invalid in math mode on input line 19`  do you mean `\ref{e}` produces P ? (I get 0.1) or that it produces a hyperlink to the wrong place?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I got 0.1 too. But the place is not right.

Comment: latex does warn: `pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{equation.0.0.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored` which means the optidef version of `\tag` isn't setting things up for hyperref, and leaving an anchor as if for the default label, which then clashes with the real equation later. I'll look if Ulrike doesn't answer first (I don't really know optidef package)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix `\theHequation` inside a `mini` environment.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{optidef}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\ui}{\mathrm{i}}% if you really want upright

\AddToHook{env/mini/begin}{%
  \edef\theHequation{mini\unexpanded\expandafter{\theequation}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mini}|s|
    {}{c^\top x}
    {\tag{P}\label{P}}
    {}
    \addConstraint{Ax}{=b}
    \addConstraint{x}{\geq 0}.
\end{mini}

\begin{align}
    1+\exp(\ui \pi) = 0 \label{e}
\end{align} 

Reference to \ref{P}

Reference to \ref{e}
    
\end{document}
```

The links will point to the correct spots.

Aside: `\i` doesn't work in math mode (and produces a dotless i anyway). If you're redefining `\i` in your real document, don't.

[image]